# differentiating between different post requests on the same page in Django views.py

Tags: python, django

I have a web page that I am looking to be able to modify dynamically with multiple post requests.  basically there are two methods that the user can submit text to be uploaded into models; one is through a text input field and the other is through a file upload field.  How do I set up my python conditionals to do this? I want to be able to differentiate between the two post request with if and statements.  What is the differentiating variable that I should use to tell these two apart. My views.py so far has the text input working.

```
def homesite(request):
corpusitems = CorpusItem.objects.order_by('name')
if (request.method == 'POST'):
    f = CorpusItemForm(request.POST)
    if f.is_valid():
        new_corpusitem = f.save()

return render(request, 'content.html', {'corpusitems': corpusitems})
```

Comment: Your logic will could go in the `CorpusItemForm`; depending on what it is you want to do.

Comment: I want to add an ifelse segment to the the first if that takes the file upload post and saves it too a variable.  I need to be able to differentiate between the two post requests with an and in the if clause.

Comment: def homesite(request):
corpusitems = CorpusItem.objects.order_by('name')
if (request.method == 'POST') and .......:
    f = CorpusItemForm(request.POST)
    if f.is_valid():
        new_corpusitem = f.save()

return render(request, 'content.html', {'corpusitems': corpusitems})

Comment: You need to do `f = CorpusItemForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Submit buttons in HTML have name and value properties. For example if you have:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Send"/>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Hello"/>
</form>
```

Then in Django you can distinguish the two submit actions by the value of `action`:

```
if request.POST['action'] == 'Send':
    # do this
elif request.POST['action'] == 'Hello':
    # do that
```

Comment: +1 janos. For anyone looking to similar things in web.py, it's nearly identical. With same html as above, you can do `post_args=web.input()` and then `if(post_args['action'] == 'Send'): #do stuff`. Hope that is helpful to someone.

Comment: How does one accomplish this in flask for GET request when a link is clicked for two forms in the same view function?